# Activar input dinamico en aun modal con javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buen dia a todos. Estoy intentando mostrar un input text en un modal en base a un dato de un select.

Tengo una tabla dinamica en la que consulto los datos desde la base de datos y esta tiene un boton para editar la informacion de cada fila, en ese modal tengo dos select uno se activa con la informacion del otro mediante javascript, me funciona para el primer modal, pero en los demas modales no funciona. Utilizo bootstrap.

Muchas gracias a quien me pueda ayudar. Este es mi codigo.

```
<table class="table table-striped2">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Ciudad y Dirección</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody class="contenidobusqueda">
            <?php
            $dbConnection = ConexionDB();
            if ($dbConnection) {
                $categ = PeopleExist($dbConnection);
                if ($categ != NULL) {
                    foreach ($categ as $cat) {
                        $Id = $cat['IdP'];
                        $NamePers = $cat['Nombre'];
                        $CiudadPers = $cat['Ciudad'];
                        $MunicipioPers = $cat['Municipio'];
                        $DepartamentoPers = $cat['Departamento'];
                        $LocacionPers = $cat['Locacion'];
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <?php echo $NamePers; ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <?php if ($LocacionPers == 'Sin especificar') {
                                    echo $MunicipioPers . '<br>' . $DireccionPers;
                                } else {
                                    echo $MunicipioPers . '<br>' . $LocacionPers . '<br>' . $DireccionPers;
                                } ?>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm mb-1 btn-outline-success" data-bs-toggle="modal"
                                    title="Editar" data-bs-target="#EditModal<?php echo $Id; ?>">Editar
                                </button>
                                <!-- Modal para editar una aptitud-->
    <div class="modal fade login-box-wrapper" id="EditModal<?php echo $Id; ?>" tabindex="-1"
        aria-labelledby="NewModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" style="margin-top:5rem">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="NewModalLabel">Editar</h1>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-5">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="ciudad">Ciudad/Municipio</label>
                                    <select name="ciudad" id="ciudad" class="selectpicker show-tick form-control"
                                        data-live-search="false">
                                        <?php
                                        echo '<option value = "' . $CiudadPers . '" selected>' . $MunicipioPers . ' (' . $DepartamentoPers . ')</option>';
                                        $dbConnection = ConexionDB();
                                        if ($dbConnection) {
                                            $Munici = GetAllCity($dbConnection);
                                            if ($Munici != NULL) {
                                                foreach ($Munici as $mun) {
                                                    echo '<option value = "' . $mun['idmunicipio_DB'] . '">' . $mun['Municipio_DB'] . ' (' . $mun['Departamento_DB'] . ')</option>';
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-6" id="locacion" style="display:none">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="locate">Localidad</label>
                                    <select name="locate" id="locate" class="form-control">
                                        <?php echo '<option value = "' . $LocacionPers . '" selected>' . $LocacionPers . '</option>'; ?>
                                        <option value="Usaquén">Usaquén</option>
                                        <option value="Chapinero">Chapinero</option>
                                        <option value="Santa Fe">Santa Fe</option>
                                        <option value="San Cristóbal"> San Cristóbal</option>
                                        <option value="Usme">Usme</option>
                                        <option value="Tunjuelito">Tunjuelito</option>
                                        <option value="Bosa">Bosa</option>
                                        <option value="Kennedy">Kennedy</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="updUser" id="updUser" class="m-2 btn btn-outline-success btn-sm"
                        value="Actualizar">&#10003;Editar</button>
                </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <?php
                    }
                } else {
                    echo '<tr><p><strong>No hay personas registradas.</strong></p></tr>';
                }
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Este es el script que utilizo para mostrar el segundo select

```
    <script>
        $('#ciudad').change(function (e) {
            if ($(this).val() == "149") {
                $('#locacion').css('display', 'block');
            } else {
                $('#locacion').css('display', 'none');
            }
        });
    </script>
```